# DateTime is not the same value in the Data Base using angularJs

Tags: angularjs

This is The Data in the sql db
[image]

and this is the AngulaJJ Ui-Calendar
[image]

**The Problem is:** the data in the db presented with another values in the UI

```js
'use strict';
app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', 'uiCalendarConfig', '$http', 'ngAuthSettings',  function ($scope, uiCalendarConfig, $http, ngAuthSettings) {
    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;
    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;

    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    //get the events data from server 
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/Event/GetEvents', {
        cache: true,
        params: {}
    }).then(function (data) {
        //get and push events data to calendar here
        console.log(data.data);
        $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
            $scope.events.push({
                title: value.EventTitle,
                description: value.EventDescription,
                start:parseInt(value.StartDate),
                end: parseInt(value.EndDate),
                allDay: value.IsFullDay,
                stick: true

            }); 
             
        });
    });
    //Calender configration in angular
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 700,
            editable: true,
            displayEventTime: false,
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function () {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="form-login-heading">Calendar</h1>
        <div ng-controller="eventController">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="bold blue" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-4 text-center center">
                    <div ng-show="SelectedEvent" class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:50px">
                        <h2 style="margin-top:0px"> Selected Event:</h2>
                        <h3 style="color:#A9A50E">{{SelectedEvent.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{SelectedEvent.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

**I used:**

start: new Date(parseInt(value.StartDate)) > Not Working

**and also used:**
   the data type in the db of this col > DateTime , Date , nvarchar. > Not Working and Same Error.

**To sum up:**
The problem is:  in **db** the date = 2018-09-09 but in the Ui-view( using angularJS)  date = 1-1-1970.

I need to know where is the problem, and how to solve it

Comment: Have you console `start: new Date(parseInt(value.StartDate))` before and after parse?

Comment: The Date you are getting is default date. It comes when your format of date is not correct.

Comment: u were right the problem was in the parsing ... it came to 2018 view ... thanks very much  ahsan ayub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you have received from service is in string format you need to convert it to javascript date object.
so in your case you can do it as follows

```
start: new Date(value.StartDate)
```